# Routing does not work

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, ipv6

I have two interfaces `wan0` and `wg0`. The routing table looks like this:

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz00::/56 dev wg0 proto static metric 20 pref medium
2a0c:xxx::/32 dev wan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a0c:xxx::/32 dev wan0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 2591957sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default proto static metric 1024 pref medium
        nexthop via 2a0c:xxx::1 dev wan0 weight 1
        nexthop via fe80::****:****:****:3780 dev wan0 weight 1
```

When I try to ping `dns.google` from the `wg0` interface, the packets are not redirected to the `wan0` interface. Why?

---

tcpdump on the `wg0` interface gives something like this:

```
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, echo request, id 1, seq 5093, length 40
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy::1 > 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unreachable address dns.google, length 88
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, echo request, id 1, seq 5094, length 40
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has dns.google, length 26
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has dns.google, length 26
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has dns.google, length 26
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy::1 > 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unreachable address dns.google, length 88
IP6 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww > dns.google: ICMP6, echo request, id 1, seq 5095, length 40
```

Checking the route via ip -6 r get shows the correct route (2001:4860:4860::8888 is dns.google):

```
❯ ip -6 r get to 2001:4860:4860::8888 from 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww iif wg0
2001:4860:4860::8888 from 2a0c:xxx:yyy:zz60::wwww via 2a0c:xxx::1 dev wan0 proto static metric 1024 iif wg0 pref medium
```

Sometimes packets are still redirected to the wan0 interface, but this happens very rarely.

Comment: Did you set the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to 1 ?

Comment: @drookie Yes, both `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding` are set to 1